There is a repository for the Administrator folder on my system when I didn't create one
The git repository at "c:\Users\Administrator" has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled. Would you like to add "node_modules" to .gitignore?
This message shows up everytime I open VS Code. But I never created this repository.
Why is there a administrator repository when I didn't create one? I tried to delete the gitignore file and githistory but it still shows up. How can I remove this repository without affecting the folder?

It seems like it has been created a repository under C:\users\administrator. I don't know if it was an accident or the reason behind tracking the whole windows' user directory, but if you don't want to track changes in that directory, just delete the hidden folder .git in C:\users\administrator.

It worked! Thanks a lot @dani-vta .
